# Y-axis on my graph isn't appearing right?

Tags: python, excel, charts, yaxis

I created a data frame from this [exel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zh9K4.png) using Pandas. I then use matplotlib to make a [bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUU9j.png). out of it. The problem is that the y-axis is completely random and I can't fix it. How do I?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import streamlit as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

st.set_page_config(page_title='Charts')
st.header('Charts')
st.subheader('Bar Chart')

excel_file = r'C:\Users\CHIRASB1\Downloads\Chart.xlsm'         # reads the exel file
sheet_name = 'Sheet4'  # calles the sheet obviously

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,                        # creates the data frame
                  sheet_name = sheet_name,
                  usecols='A:S',
                  header=0,
                  dtype=str,
                  nrows=18)
y = df['1-Jun'].tolist().shape
x = df['Rule Exception Impacted Apps'].tolist()


plt.bar(x, y)
plt.plot()
plt.title('Total Rule Impacts vs. Date')
plt.ylabel("Total Rule Impacts")
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.savefig('Chart.png')
image = Image.open('Chart.png')
st.image(image, caption='Uploaded Image.', use_column_width=True, color='blue')
```

Comment: Never used dataframes so I can't help you with that part, but `plt.plot('r')` is responsible for that `r` tick on your y-axis. I don't know what you intended by that line but all it does is mess up your plot with a string; when I try it, it erases all my y-ticks. I don't even know why that's allowed, I can't imagine a purpose for it.

Comment: Yeah got rid of it. The r is gone but the rest of the number are still wonky.